# How to upgrade from AWS WAF v1 to WAF V2

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have AWS WAF Classic that I would like to upgrade to WAFv2 without having to run a Terraform script to create WAFv2.Please how can I upgrade the current WAF classic to WAFv2 without disturbing the current classic configuration using Terraform

Comment: I don't think this is possible using TF. The WAF migration process is an imperative process that TF does not appear to have support for. Your options are either to create a new ACL with wafv2 and then switch over to it, or follow the migration steps and manually import relevant resources into TF. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-migrating-procedure-automatic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking a migration of a service about a cloud resource (waf classic to waf2 in your case) you should use new terraform resource blocks for the new service. So no one can write your terraform codes from scratch or refactor them. You should provide new terrafom codes then create new resources from them. Terraform import is also not applicable since the waf2 is completely different than waf and of course terraform codes are different such as "aws_waf_web_acl"  "aws_wafv2_web_acl".

I can say that it is not a big issue, just start from scratch. The major change is lack of aws_waf_rule anymore. It is in the description of acl.